# Hi I am trying to Design a VF page which will implement "Show" and "Hide" button toggle I am facing some problem

Tags: apex, visualforce

Controller Class:

```
public class popUpController {

    Public List<Lead> leadList{get;set;}
    public Boolean showHide{get;set;}
    public Boolean displayPopup{get;set;}
    //public Boolean hide{get;set;}

    public popUpController(){
        showHide = false;
    }

    public void show(){
        showHide = true; 
        displayPopup = true;
        leadList = new List<Lead>();
        leadList = [SELECT Name,Company,Status FROM Lead limit 1000];

    }
    public void  hide(){
        showHide = false; 
        displayPopup = false;
    }
    public PageReference cancelLead(){
        PageReference objCancel = new PageReference('00Q/o');
        objCancel.setRedirect(true);
        return objCancel;
    }

    public List<Lead>  getLeads(){
        showHide = false; 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!leadList}" var="l" rendered="d">
            <apex:column value="{!l.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!l.Company}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!l.Status}"/>                
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons id="d"  rendered="{!displayPopup}">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!show}" value="Show" rendered="{!NOT(showHide)}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Hide" action="{!hide}" rendered="{!showHide}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelLead}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: My advice would be to use JavaScript here rather than Apex to take extra, unnecessary load off the server.

Comment: It's not working Properly

Comment: There's something I don't understand. When you click on the "Hide" button, the boolean "displayPopup" is set to false. So your buttons are supposed to be hidden. So then you will not be able to show them again. Because your button "Show" will not be displayed.

Comment: What is it doing that is improper?

Comment: Now I have make changes and it's working fine ....
Thank you all for reply

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in your Visualforce Page, specifically this block:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons id="d"  rendered="{!displayPopup}">
  <apex:commandButton action="{!show}" value="Show" rendered="{!NOT(showHide)}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Hide" action="{!hide}" rendered="{!showHide}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelLead}" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Although you're specifying when a component should be rendered, you're not telling each button to re-render the block once an action takes place. Pretty easy to fix, given you've already given the `<apexPageBlockButtons>` and Id of "d", you just need to add `rerender="d"` to your `<apex:commandbutton>`.

I strongly advise you to change this over to JavaScript though. This will mean that the User's machine will be processing this, relatively simple job rather than the server.

Comment: @Martin Actually I am trying to design a VF page which will implement Show and Hide button toggle. Which will show records in tabular format and there will be two buttons show/hide and cancel.